# Oracle's empty_clob() in HSQL

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, hsqldb

I am using HSQL as in-memory database to "mock" for testing purposes Oracle's database used on production.

I got stucked on one compatibility issue between HSQL and Oracle. Namely, it complains that EMPTY_CLOB() is lacking.

**Is there any way to provide Oracle's empty_clob() function to HSQL's context?**

I tried e.g. declaring

```
CREATE FUNCTION empty_clob()
RETURNS CLOB
NO SQL
LANGUAGE JAVA PARAMETER STYLE JAVA
EXTERNAL NAME 'CLASSPATH:com.example.HsqlUtil.emptyClob'
```

and implementing this function in Java code

```
package com.example;

public class HsqlUtil {
    public static java.sql.Clob emptyClob() throws SQLException {
        return oracle.sql.CLOB.getEmptyCLOB();
        // return new org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCClob(""); also does not work
    }
}
```

but it results in

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Java execution: EMPTY_CLOB
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Routine.invokeJavaMethod(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Routine.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.FunctionSQLInvoked.getValueInternal(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.FunctionSQLInvoked.getValue(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.getInsertData(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
... 25 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: incompatible data type in conversion
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.types.ClobType.convertJavaToSQL(Unknown Source)
```

**Solution:**

As suggested by fredt, is to provide SQL function as below:

```
create function empty_clob() 
returns VARCHAR (20)
return '';
```

Comment: why not just use [XE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/overview/index.html)?

Comment: You don't need `empty_clob()` neither in Oracle nor in HSQLDB

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using empty_clob() function in my production code. I want to run tests on this code but using in-memory HSQLDB instead of Oracle DB.

Comment: I understand that, but you don't need the `empty_clob()` - not even for Oracle. And as you can remove it from your Oracle code you could run it on HSQLDB then. (Although I am not convinced that running tests on a different DBMS makes sense - but that is a different discussion).

Comment: [empty_clob()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions047.htm) is used in production code. Do you know what code can I use instead of that function?

Comment: I assume you need that during an `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, please see my answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10728626/330315 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8139775/330315 that code should work without changes in Oracle and HSQLDB (and many other DBMS/JDBC drivers actually)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing the empty_clob() function as returning an empty VARCHAR string, instead of returning a CLOB.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the answer, which works BTW, if you are creating a JDBC script and created a schema, then you have to add

```
create function empty_clob() 
returns VARCHAR (20)
return '';
```

before you add

```
CREATE SCHEMA schema_name
```