# Insert big string (>4000) into Clob jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, clob

I'm stuck on this:
I've followed the hundreds procedures found on the internet to store a big string into a clob object and then to oracle db.
In particular:
a prepared statement (insert into) with empty clob:

```
executer.add("S_NOTA_GLOBALE", CLOB.getEmptyCLOB());
```

the line above is to populate the the bind vars in the query which is very long.
So, at this point, let's say that I've an empty clob inserted (which is actually true). Then:

```
String sqlText = "SELECT S_NOTA_GLOBALE " +
                 "FROM   SN_DENUNCE " +
                 "WHERE  ID_DENUNCIA = ? " +
                 "FOR UPDATE";


PreparedStatement psClobUpdate= conn.prepareStatement(sqlText);
psClobUpdate.setLong(1,denuncia.getId());  
ResultSet  rset = psClobUpdate.executeQuery();
rset.next();
CLOB  notaGlobale = (CLOB) ((ResultSet) rset).getClob("S_NOTA_GLOBALE");


Writer writer = notaGlobale.setCharacterStream(0);

try {
    writer.write(denuncia.getNotaGlobale().toCharArray());
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    rset.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Another  preparedStatement for updating the clob.
The problem is that once I retrieve the resultSet, it is empty, which is reasonable(?), since I've just inserted an empty clob. I don't know where I'm getting wrog, but surely I'm getting crazy.

The solution I've implemented is taken from the following link (attempt #5):
http://fahdshariff.blogspot.it/2008/07/big-strings-and-oracle-clobs.html

**NOTE**:
jdbc driver 11.2.0.4.0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8139775/330315

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461. Of course I'm trying to bind a Long type, where Long is a character data type. Why this exception? Thank you for your reply, but please help me figuring out what's going on. @a_horse_with_no_name