# How do I use an IN OUT CLOB parameter defined in a Stored Proc in Oracle JDBC?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have the following stored procedure defined:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NOTIFY_INSERT (
  FLAG IN VARCHAR2,
  MESSAGE IN OUT CLOB,
  SEQ_NO OUT NUMBER
) 
AS
BEGIN
...
END;
```

Now I'm trying to call this stored proc in JDBC. However, I get an exception saying "java.sql.SQLException: Parameter Type Conflict". This is raised from the line

```
call.execute();
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the second parameter, which is a CLOB.

**Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?**

Thanks for your help.

```
Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
CallableStatement call = null;
try {
    call = connection.prepareCall("{ call NOTIFY_INSERT (?,?,?) }");
    call.setString(1, flag);
    call.registerOutParameter(2, Types.CLOB);
    call.setString(2, message);
    call.registerOutParameter(3, Types.NUMERIC);
    call.execute();
    sequenceNo = call.getLong(3);
    message = call.getString(2);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (call != null) {
        try { call.close(); } catch (SQLException sqle) {}
    }
}
```

JDBC Exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter Type Conflict
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2480)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4356)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4595)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:10100)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:5693)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that you can pass a String directly to a parameter of type CLOB.  When attempting to bind a CLOB parameter, you can do the following:

If you already have a `Clob`:

```
call.setClob(1, clob);
```

If you want to convert a `String` into a `Clob`:

```
call.setCharacterStream(1, new StringReader(string), string.length());
```

If you want to set a null CLOB:

```
call.setNull(1, Types.CLOB);
```

You can also see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678060/execute-sql-statement-via-jdbc-with-clob-binding).

Comment: I still have to test this solution, but it looks like the right way to go. I'll let you know if I'm able to get it working...

Comment: @LateDownvoter: Why the downvote?  And why 1 1/2 months later?

Comment: Not sure who downvoted, but I up voted. This was the proper answer.