# JPA EclipseLink Call NamedStoredProcedureQuery with Clob parameter (IN and OUT)

Tags: jpa, stored-procedures, eclipselink, procedure, clob

Prompt how better to call the procedure with IN-parameters (Clob) and then parse the OUT-parameters. (Clob)

For JDBC I found [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220954/how-do-i-use-an-in-out-clob-parameter-defined-in-a-stored-proc-in-oracle-jdbc). How I can impliment it with JPA and EclipseLink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Clob:

```
    Clob clobR = null;
    try {
        Connection conn = em.unwrap(Connection.class);
        java.sql.Connection con2 = conn.getMetaData().getConnection();
        clobR = con2.createClob();
        clobR.setString(START_POSITION, data);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Call procedure:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery(name);
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(paramName, type, mode);
    query.setParameter(paramName, value);
```

Comment: This didn't work. I got a `NullPointerException` on this line: `java.sql.Connection con2 = conn.getMetaData().getConnection();`. The `Connection` here is an interface not a class. Is that what you really wanted to do?